# Google BigQuery: Add new column to a table with constant value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ddl

I would like to know a way of adding one additional column to a BigQuery table, that will populate all the rows for this newly created column with specific constant value.
I know how to create column with NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE project_id.dataset.table
ADD COLUMN A STRING
```

But my goal is to also add the ingestion time with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function. Is it even possible with one command? Or maybe I need to apply subsequently some second command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a solution is to use another query after the mentioned one:

```
UPDATE project_id.dataset.table SET A = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS STRING) WHERE 1=1
```